# How to make an individual SVG ID a button

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, svg

So I really need to make each individual path ID in my SVG its own button. I have tried adding  around each of the  tags, but it actually just makes the entire svg disappear.

PLEASE HELP!

```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="262px" height="644px" viewBox="128 65.25 262 644" enable-background="new 128 65.25 262 644" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="skull">
<path id="skull" opacity="0.5" fill="#5CCAE8" enable-background="new    " d="M237.026 122.5 c1.92 7.2 3.3 7.6 3 10.028c-0.341 2.388-0.375 10.5 10.1 11.58c10.522 1.1 22.9 1.6 26.282-5.134 c0 0 1.338-8.834 2.817-10.267c1.479-1.433 0.765-4.775 1.958-6.208c1.192-1.433 3.485-23.877-1.958-32.233 c-5.444-8.357-7.435-12.655-21.124-12.655c-13.69 0-19.059 8.118-20.193 10.028c-1.137 1.91-1.455 5.253-2.251 6.5 c-0.795 1.273-1.113 6.048-1.272 7.958c-0.16 1.9 0 14.5 0.8 16.873C236.002 121.4 237 122.5 237 122.477z"/></g>
<g id="humerus">
    <path id="humerus" opacity="0.5" fill="#9B4F9E" enable-background="new    " d="M190.635 197.309c-2.093-5.987-1.962-8.47-0.813-10.126 c1.147-1.655 0.957-1.908 3.312-2.478c2.356-0.57 3.695-1.97 5.67-1.458c1.973 0.5 3.3 0.7 5.6 3.8 c2.289 3.1 0.8 5.3 0.8 5.35s-2.737 0.059-3.824 2.86c-1.086 2.8-2.602 43.292-3.114 45.3 c-0.512 1.973-3.397 17.25-3.02 20.943c0.378 3.7 4.7 19.6 4.8 21.845c0.124 2.3 1.5 5.67-3.638 6.3 c0 0 0.7 2.516-1.503 2.243c-2.192-0.273-4.356-1.041-6.52-1.808c-2.163-0.767-7.004-0.327-6.808-3.256 c0.194-2.929-0.565-5.54 2.876-8.911c3.442-3.371 5.869-32.016 6.592-37.428S190.635 197.3 190.6 197.309z"/>
    <path id="humerus" opacity="0.5" fill="#9B4F9E" enable-background="new    " d="M326.388 196.912c2.059-5.999 1.914-8.481 0.758-10.129 c-1.158-1.647-0.97-1.903-3.329-2.46c-2.359-0.556-3.706-1.948-5.678-1.424c-1.97 0.524-3.307 0.724-5.577 3.8 c-2.27 3.072-0.788 5.354-0.788 5.354s2.738 0 3.8 2.838c1.102 2.8 2.9 43.3 3.4 45.2 c0.524 2 3.5 17.2 3.1 20.926c-0.356 3.697-4.573 19.58-4.686 21.873c-0.111 2.293-1.424 5.7 3.7 6.3 c0 0-0.675 2.5 1.5 2.234c2.191-0.286 4.35-1.065 6.511-1.843c2.156-0.781 7.001-0.369 6.79-3.296 c-0.213-2.927 0.533-5.542-2.929-8.895c-3.462-3.35-6.054-31.981-6.808-37.389C325.444 234.6 326.4 196.9 326.4 196.912z"/>
```

```
</svg>
```

Comment: I edited my post just now since it cut off so much of my code by accident. Essentially, I have an svg skeleton, where each path should link to its own page. Is there actually an easier way to do this other than splitting everything up? Or is that still the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking things down so you're not trying to do everything in one SVG tag.  The SVG tag should basically just be your canvas to create the buttons - you can embed shapes and text within the SVG tag, with assigned IDs, to do the rest.  Here's a code example and link http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="10cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 100 30" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <desc>Example Use01 - Simple case of 'use' on a 'rect'</desc>
  <defs>
    <rect id="MyRect" width="60" height="10"/>
  </defs>
  <rect x=".1" y=".1" width="99.8" height="29.8"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".2" />
  <use x="20" y="10" xlink:href="#MyRect" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I edited my post just now since it cut off so much of my code by accident. Essentially, I have an svg skeleton, where each path should link to its own page. 

Is there actually an easier way to do this other than splitting everything up? Or is that still the best way to do it?